# DokuWiki Installation on Windows server 2003 using IIS problems

Tags: php, iis, permissions, windows-server-2003, dokuwiki

I am trying to install DokuWiki on a windows 2003 server and using IIS 7.2 and PHP 5. I have gone on to IIS and created a virtual directory that points to where I extracted DokuWiki, I have set up all the permissions for that folder ensuring that it has rwx on all folders and sub folders. The virtual directory has rwx permissions enabled. The first problem I had was that php reported a missing file which was PassHash.class.php which I just created the blank file but before I added that file the logs reported

```
[20-May-2015 10:36:51] PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\dokuwiki/inc/PassHash.class.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\dokuwiki\install.php on line 12

[20-May-2015 10:36:51] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'C:\dokuwiki/inc/PassHash.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\dokuwiki\install.php on line 12
```

But once I added the blank file it displays this:

[image]

I am aware that it is a permissions issue but I don't know how to add the permissions to those directories or even where they are located. Also did anyone else have to create that blank file ? seems a little odd to me. Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse to the dokuwiki/ directory and Check the properties of the data/ folder. Ensure that the Internet Guest Account(IUSR), the appropriate web server account or Server Group(IIS_IUSRS) has Folder level “Write” permissions to the data/ folder.

Browse to the dokuwiki/ directory and Check the properties of the conf/ folder. Ensure that the Internet Guest Account(IUSR), the appropriate web server account or Server Group(IIS_IUSRS) has Folder level “Write” permissions to the conf/ folder.

In IIS Manager left click the site name
Click “Edit Permissions” in the Actions pane OR right click and choose “Edit Permissions” from the shortcut menu.
Click the Security tab
Click the Edit button
Click the Add button
Click the Locations button and choose the local server name
Now type in IUSR and click OK, and OK again.

After this, install.php should work.

Comment: I know it says that on the dokuwik website but there is not data or conf directory in there

Comment: That means you done goofed somewhere. I just downloaded it from the site and it exists. Proof: http://puu.sh/hU52V/b1b454d8a1.png

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful can you send me a link to the download please? I downloaded the latest version from the dokuwiki website. Im using 7zip to extract.

Comment: What? I got it from the same source too : http://download.dokuwiki.org/src/dokuwiki/dokuwiki-stable.tgz  It's a tar.gz file so you will have to open it twice with 7z.

Comment: Nevermind, It was a silly me problem. Can you put your helpful advice in an answer so I can mark it as correct and upvote